# If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first in java generics. Why?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-parameter

I was referring to this [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) .
**If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first** . What I feel is it should allow in any order.

**Why do java has such restriction ? Is there any specific reason behind this?**

> Multiple Bounds
>
> The preceding example illustrates the use of a type parameter with a
>   single bound, but a type parameter can have multiple bounds:
>
> A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types
>   listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be
>   specified first. For example:

```
Class A { /* ... */ } 
interface B { /* ... */ }
interface C { /* ...
 */ }

class D <T extends A & B & C> { /* ... */ }
```

> If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:

```
 class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }  // compile-time error ,but why ?
```

Comment: You have answered your question even before asking it. Now, if the specification says so then compiler should do so...

Comment: My question is why is there such type of specification ? not why compiler has implemented this way.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there can only be a single class there; each Java class (except `java.lang.Object`, which is a special case as the root of the hierarchy) can only ever inherit from a single other class. There can be multiple interfaces, but at most one class. This enormously simplifies the processing of the type hierarchy and the object construction process.

Given that, the language designers decided that the class has to be listed first in the bounds (if it is present at all). There's actually no deep reason for that — the compiler could have coped just fine with enforcing the only-one-class restriction without the ordering — but it does make things somewhat easier to teach as there's a simple rule: *if you're using a class as a generic type bound, put it first*.

Answer (score 1):

Might be they just to group the interfaces together, separate from the class.

If `T` was a class then it would look as following:

```
public class T extends A implements B, C {
```

But in generics there is no `implements`, and only `extends`. So, the constraint could be only to make us list the class itself first and then list the interfaces due to the lack of the key word `implements`.

Answer (score 0):

[`JLS # 4.4. Type Variables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. **If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed.** If a bound is declared, it consists of either:

- a single type variable `T`, or
- a class or interface type `T` possibly followed by interface types `I1 &
  ... & In`

Comment: thats what my question is. why ?

Comment: As mentioned above you could specify ONE class and MULTIPLE interfaces

Comment: Java only supports single inheritance.

Comment: @AmitD Java supports single inheritance from class but multiple interface implementations. Note that maybe OP is confused because you `extend` a class an `implement` one or many interfaces, but when templating you use the `extend` keyword for both classes and interfaces and maybe this is the explanation OP's looking for.

Comment: @AmitD "multiple bounds with & operator bounds are only applicable for interfaces not classes" - obviously that's not true. One class can be specified.

Comment: @AmitD note that the problem is because `A` is class and `B` and `C` are interfaces, the order of `T extends` matters as defining a class with `extend` and `implement` keywords.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is because of Single inheritance. If type bound is not specified with type then Object is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say as `"A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound."` and it seems Java asks you to indicate the extends First in a class declaration that would be the reason. (On the other hand a class can only extend one other class)